# Jwplayer - Error: jwplayer(...).setup is not a function

Tags: angularjs, jwplayer, ng-dialog

I have to show jwplayer in a popup, for popups I am using ngDialog(angular), code for ngDialog is below:

```
$scope.showVideoPlayerPopup = function(video_path)
{
    $scope.ngDialog = ngDialog;
            ngDialog.open({
                animation: true,
                scope:$scope,
                template:'<div id="video_popup"></div>',
                plain: true,
                //className: 'ngdialog-theme-default',
                closeByDocument: true
                //backdrop : 'static'
            });
        playVideo(video_path);
}
```

play video function called above contains code for jwplayer, which is below:

```
<script>
    function playVideo(video_path)
    {
        jwplayer("video_popup").setup({
            file: video_path,
            width: "600px",
            height: "600px",
            stretching: "bestfit",
        });
    }

</script>
```

when I use the same jwplayer code for simple html code which is without popup it works fine but I try to put my html in popup it gives me below error:

> Error: jwplayer(...).setup is not a function

**update**

Files I have included:

```
<script src="https://content.jwplatform.com/libraries/qAkRysIB.js"></script>
```

Comment: Did you add jwplayer.js file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Ensure the jwplayer src is included (you likely already did but in case not:)

   #### Update 11/2021

   see the section [**Cloud-hosted**](https://developer.jwplayer.com/jwplayer/docs/jw8-add-a-player-library#cloud-hosted) on the documentation page [Add a player library](https://developer.jwplayer.com/jwplayer/docs/jw8-add-a-player-library). This will require [obtaining a JWPlayer account](https://info.jwplayer.com/sign-up/).

   > 1. From your [Player Downloads & Keys](https://dashboard.jwplayer.com/#/players/downloads) page, scroll down to the **Cloud Hosted Player Libraries** section.
   > 2. In the **Cloud Hosted Player Libraries** section, select a **Player Title** from the dropdown menu.
   > 3. Copy the **Cloud Player Library Url**.
   > 4. Within the `<head>` of your page, copy and paste the URL to the player library.
   >
   >    ```
   >    <script src="{cloud_hosted_player_library_url}"></script>
   >    ```
2. Ensure that the panel has loaded before calling the `setup` function. One way to do this is to register an event listener for `ngDialog.opened` from the ngDialog (see the [**Events**](https://github.com/likeastore/ngDialog#user-content-events) section of the [ngDialog readme](https://github.com/likeastore/ngDialog#readme)):

   ```
   $scope.$on('ngDialog.opened', function (e, $dialog) {
     playVideo();
   });
   ```

Comment: Thank you @Sam. Worked perfectly. Saved my day!!

Comment: Where do the docs describe `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://p.jwpcdn.com/6/10/jwplayer.js"></script>` is necessary?

Comment: @Philll_t I can't remember where I found that URL but I have since updated the answer to be congruent with the latest documentation since the previous URL didn't appear to work anymore with the jsbin sample.

Answer (score 1):

Yes...because your div tag with id "current_video_path" has to be there in DOM before jwplayer(...).setup script can work...May be you can add some delay using $timeout or setTimeout so it will have enough time to render div in popup before this script can wrok..

Comment: How can someone determine delay time, always use callback in such cases.

Comment: @Sweety Webashlar : I have created <input type="hidden" id="current_video_path" value=''> in my DOM already. Thanks anyway.

Comment: yes...can be done..i just wanted to make him realize that there must be timing issue...that was only my main concern. and that was options to quickly check if it was same case for him or not..